# background colour not applying in <a> tag

Tags: css, reactjs

html

```
 <a ref={resume} href='../assets/resume.pdf' download onMouseLeave={() => setMouse(true)} onMouseEnter={() => setMouse(false)} className='resume-container'>
```

css

```
.resume-container {    
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: .5vw;
    margin-right: .5vw;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #D4B44A;
    
    
    
    
}
```

all the other properties seems to work, and if I make that  to div it will work. but background wont apply to  tag

Comment: Tried here https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-night-tlc1ls and its working .

Answer (score 2):

The CSS block looks okay but the A tag might benefit from enclosing a couple things in quotes and changing className to just class.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .resume-container {    
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: .5vw;
    margin-right: .5vw;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #D4B44A;   
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <a href="" class="resume-container">Some Link</a>

  <a 
    ref={resume}
    href="../assets/resume.pdf" download 
    onMouseLeave="{() => setMouse(true)}"
    onMouseEnter="{() => setMouse(false)}"
    class="resume-container"
  >Another Link</a>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Links require content to be visible.

```css
.resume-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: .5vw;
  margin-right: .5vw;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #D4B44A;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="resume-container">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Maniraj Murugan mentioned in his comment, the code should work.
A possible issue is that there is another background-color property applied which prevents the one inside `resume-container` class to take effect.

You can try adding `!important` like so: `background-color: #D4B44A !important` to override the previous properties.

Answer (score 1):

Change `className='resume-container'` to `class="resume-container"`. An `a` tag also requires you have text so that it will display, in the code snippet you provided there is neither text nor a closing tag. I also had problems with `href='../assets/resume.pdf'` and `onMouseLeave={() => setMouse(true)} onMouseEnter={() => setMouse(false)}` whenever I tried this code out. Change the apostrophes to quotes with your href and wrap your Javascript in quotes.

Final result below.

```
 <a ref={resume} href="../assets/resume.pdf" download onMouseLeave="{() => setMouse(true)} onMouseEnter={() => setMouse(false)}" class="resume-container">Text</a>
```